# How to retrieve all items across all sites under a hub?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I am building a SPFX web part (React) where I need to retrieve every item in every list in every site under the Hub site/site collection.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Comment: use search api to get all the items within the hub site or site collection https://msisgreat.net/2018/09/24/search-rest-api-for-sharepoint-multiple-use-cases/

Comment: Thank you sir that should help me out :)